# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable while using lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to use lambda function with `filter()` but getting error: `"TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"`.

My code is as below:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
newlist = list(filter(lambda a:(a%2==0), list1))
print(newlist)
```

Expected output:

```
[2,4,6,8]
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-48-139f323ff9a1> in <module>()
      1 list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
----> 2 newlist = list(filter(lambda a:(a%2==0), list1))
      3 print(newlist)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Note:- If we use the command as `"newlist = tuple(filter(lambda a:(a%2==0), list1))"` we are getting output as below & there is not error:

```
(2, 4, 6, 8)
```

Comment: You probably have a variable named `list` somewhere in your code (don't name your variables with built-ins).

Comment: Seems like you defined something as `list`, and its masking the built-in function

Comment: If this is in the interactive shell, use `del list` to get rid of the variable (and get the builtin type back); if this is a script, check your variables and change the name.

Comment: You should be using a list comprehension for this anyway: `newlist = [item for item in list1 if item % 2 == 0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably defined something as a list somewhere else, try to reset your IDE,
I copied your code (the 3 lines of code you posted) into my jupyter notebook and it worked perfectly
[as seen in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AMrF.png)